# What are these little black lines in this model's render?

Tags: topology

[image: model with black lines]

Here is the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YNLehfyhDKlli38UJtu8iA8EP_Au-yHG/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your geometry is much denser than it needs to be .. (I managed to decimate to 0.05 without degradation) but it's not a good starting-point for clean simplification.. do you have an SVG version of the logo, so we can demonstrate?

Comment: To the title Q ... those are hidden edges ... is it possible you are using Freestyle feature? (I cant open your file).

Comment: No idea what Freestyle does but it was checked and unchecking it fixed it! Thank you guys for the feedback.

Comment: Here is the SVG Robin since I'm new to this and curious about geometry. Is this high density also why I'm getting that awkward, non-smooth texture on the sides of the emblem? densityhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1mPi_pL5LETBG8pn-rJiN36foco4NXqRX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308253/2214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vklidu said - you have checked the freestyle option in the render settings. If you uncheck it, the lines are gone:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow thanks so much