# What is this lined texture on the sides of this model?

Tags: geometry

[image]

The geometry's density is very high but I imagine even if it were not these lines would still be there, only further apart. But I am new to Blender so any info would help. Just curious how to smoothen everything.

Here is the .blend file and SVG I created it from: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15jw_y64vr8nWJhg2Hujys_twRFq5zaqM?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: Hi Jason, it would be helpful if you provided more information on the object in the image. Concerning artifacts, there could be several causes. It could be caused by the mesh so, it would be helpful to see the geometry of the mesh (wireframe). It might also be the texture so, it would be helpful to see the texture setup. Or the render settings.

Comment: Bad topology ... if you would follow my link in comment of your [previous Q](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308058/what-are-these-little-black-lines-in-this-models-render#comment533741_308058) you get smooth result https://imgur.com/ssRyviL ... just beveling such shape is not an easy, you would have to manually care about some overlaps.

Comment: Thanks for your all your help. I had to go for the holidays but am fully back. It looks like you're referring to the Limited Dissolve so I tried it and got this odd result: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ExKhZyIpqcaP-Ybm0hkAYM6OJRJsxpWs?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In Object Mode: <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on the *Object > Shade Smooth*.